# How to multiply decimals out of variable of type Number in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say I have an number which is equal to `288.65` and I want to multiply out the decimal point to achieve the desired result of `28865`

If I simply just try say `console.log(288.65 * 100)` it will return `28864.999999999996` I am not sure why it is doing this, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this value fiinancial in nature? If so, my advice would be to completely stay away from floating-point math.

Comment: alert(parseFloat(((288.65 * 1)*100).toFixed(3)));

Comment: The only problem is that I am using typescript and a value can either be declared as a number, I can't really be specific and declare it as a float or a double etc.

Comment: Cant you use math.round to ensure that you always get the multiplication in an integer form?

Comment: I've done what was suggested in the answer posted by @HR01M8055 and it seems to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) and with [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

> The Math.ceil() function always rounds a number up to the next largest
> integer.
>
> The Math.round() function returns the value of a number rounded to the
> nearest integer.

```js
const num = 288.65;

const result1 = Math.round(num * 100);
const result2 = Math.ceil(num * 100);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Note: this is going to work if the error is less than the target, else, this would round up the number. E.g: `28865.000000000002` -> `28866`

Comment: Works for this specific case... But... Supposing the conversion goes the other side of the intended value?